# JavaScript - Filter out two arrays and take out dupes

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
var sellersDatabase = [
  { name: 'Mark', start_date: '2017-06-27' },
  { name: 'Jane', start_date: '2017-06-27' }
];

var sellersAPICall = [
  { name: 'Mark', start_date: '2017-06-27' },
  { name: 'Joe', start_date: '2017-06-22' },
  { name: 'Steven', start_date: '2017-04-11' },
  { name: 'Jane', start_date: '2017-06-27' }
];
```

How would, using either ES6 or Lodash, get the difference of those not included in the first array? Yes, I've tried lodash's `difference()`.

So, my expected output would be:

```
var toInsertIntoDB = [
  { name: 'Joe', start_date: '2017-06-22' },
  { name: 'Steven', start_date: '2017-04-11' }
];
```

---

Doing this:

`javascript
const toInsertToDB = _.difference(sellersDatabase, sellersAPICall);
console.log(toInsertToDB);`

outputs:

`[{
    "name": "Mark",
    "start_date": "2017-06-27"
}, {
    "name": "Jane",
    "start_date": "2017-06-27"
}]`

(when I want the opposite)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are comparing array of objects, and not primitives, use [`_.differenceBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#differenceBy), and state by which property the object should be compared. In addition the `sellersAPICall` array should be the 1st (the reference array).

```js
var sellersDatabase = [
  { name: 'Mark', start_date: '2017-06-27' },
  { name: 'Jane', start_date: '2017-06-27' }
];

var sellersAPICall = [
  { name: 'Mark', start_date: '2017-06-27' },
  { name: 'Joe', start_date: '2017-06-22' },
  { name: 'Steven', start_date: '2017-04-11' },
  { name: 'Jane', start_date: '2017-06-27' }
];

var result = _.differenceBy(sellersAPICall, sellersDatabase, 'name');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And if you want to compare 2 properties, you can use a callback function that concatenates both values:

```js
var sellersDatabase = [
  { name: 'Mark', start_date: '2017-06-27' },
  { name: 'Jane', start_date: '2017-06-27' }
];

var sellersAPICall = [
  { name: 'Mark', start_date: '2017-06-27' },
  { name: 'Joe', start_date: '2017-06-22' },
  { name: 'Steven', start_date: '2017-04-11' },
  { name: 'Jane', start_date: '2017-06-27' }
];

var result = _.differenceBy(sellersAPICall, sellersDatabase, function(o) {
  return o.name + '-' + o.start_date;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, man! Should have kept reading. I might have possible sellers with same name. Is there any way the check for `name` AND `start_date`? I can use `_.differenceWith(sellersAPICall, sellersDatabase, _.isEqual);` it seems.

Comment: You haven't wrote that in your question, so I couldn't keep reading :) You can still use `_.differenceBy()` - see 2nd example.

Comment: @Ori Drori: in your second example return `o.name + '-' + o.date;` should be return `o.name + '-' + o.start_date;`